# jQuery page show the data got from json_encode in php

Tags: php, jquery, json

I want to show data in jQuery while the data got from php in json_encode function.
There are three file in all.
json.html

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="test.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

test.js

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $.getJSON("json.php",function(json){
  
  alert(json.a);
  console.log(json.a);
 });

});
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
function getA(){
 $.getJSON("json.php",function(json){
  echo json.$a;
 })
}
}
```

json.php

```html
<?php
header('Content-type:application/json');
$a=3;
echo json_encode($a);
?>
```

when I run the code,It  shows as follows:
test.js:4SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier 'json'

Thanks to what you said, the former problem was solved.But something unbelieviable happens.
I have changed test.js as follows:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){

 $.getJSON("json.php",function(json){   
  document.write(json.a1.length);
  document.write(json.a.length);
 });     
});
```

json.php

```html
<?php
// header('Content-type:application/json');
$a = array('a1' =>aaaaa ,'b2'=>bb ,'c3'=>cc);
echo json_encode($a);
?>
```

This time,browser tells me 'a' is not an object ,but 'a1' is a object.Why did the elements not array passed to js?

Comment: echo json.$a //this is php and not javaScript

Comment: Do you mean I should remove the "echo"?

Comment: yes, and use print, console.log or alert, in JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

if you want to get the output in your test.js then you should modify your code in json.php as follows

```
<?php
    $data array('a' => 3);
    echo json_encode($data);
```

`json_encode($data)` will output a `{"a":3}` which is a javascript object that which allow you to use your code in test.js

```
     $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "json.php",
        success: function(data) {
            alert(json.a);// will alert 3
            console.log(json.a);// will print 3
        }
    });
```

Comment: I have done what you said as the edited problem.But nothing happens.

Comment: In that case the problem is in the function you used to call you `json.php`
check the code above I updated it into ajax call.

Comment: are you sure that your jquery library is working properly?
try to change it to
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I tried it.But nothing changed.The problem is getJSON transmitted the  element of array not array itself as an object. Maybe I expressed not clearly.I don't know if you can understand?

Comment: As I said use ajax instead of getJSON because it will not return the element of the array.

Answer (score 0):

echo is a PHP command and not JavaScript. See the example:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.getJSON("https://viacep.com.br/ws/89208540/json/",function(json){
       console.log(json.localidade);
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have edited it presented in the edited question.But this time nothing happens.Can you tell me what happens?

Comment: To access the "a" element, use like an index of an array, OK? Like this: $a["a"]=3; echo json_encode($a);

Comment: And debug your code to see what's wrong. Firstly acess the php in your browser and see what's the response. Next step: stringify your json in JavaScript: alert(JSON.stringify(json));

Comment: Did you mean change the variable into array?But I can't access the variable defined in php file in js way?

Comment: No, you can't. The return of php is a Json object. And the json_encode function transform your array in a Json object and you access this json object in js. See the documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: Thank you for what you said. I have assign my value using array as I edited in problems. But this time , nothing happens either. I don't know where lying the problems.

Answer (score 0):

Replace `echo json.$a;` in test.js to `alert(json.a);`

Comment: I have edited it . But this time nothing happens.It didn't alert anything.

Comment: To access the "a" element, use like an index of an array, OK? Like this: 
$a["a"]=3;
echo json_encode($a);

Answer (score 0):

In your json.php file use array to assign your value e.g,

```
<?php
$a=array('a'=>3);
echo json_encode($a);
?>
```

Comment: why did you add "echo" in php file? I have seen many people coding in that way. Do you mean echo the thing in php page? In my opinion, $a is still not a  json in this way. So i assigned json_encode($a) to $b.But It didn't work.